# What is to be done with a thread that was locked after beign vandalized

Tags: discussion, specific-question

the thread [Why are religious exemptions to anti-discrimination laws legal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79097/why-are-religious-exemptions-to-anti-discrimination-laws-legal) was vandalized with an irrelevant and abusive attack on a poster, on SE, and on society generally, using highly offensive language.

These edits were reverted, the user who made them blocked, and the thread has been locked. All quite proper, and my thanks to the mods involved.. But the thread (before the vandalistic edit, and after it was rolled back) was a legitimate and useful question, and it may be that others will wish to provide legitimate answers or comments.

How do we move from the current locked state to a more normal situation for trhis thread, and any others that might be vandalized?

Comment: It takes a bit of work to handle this sort of thing.  After suspending the user I undeleted the thread and did a rollback of the question.  I also requested redaction of the vandalized revision, as well as disassociation of the user so that his account can be destroyed without irrevocably deleting that Q&A.

Comment: Answering in comment because I'm not sure if this situation and its custodial details merit memorialization on this Meta.  To the extent that it's a a mess that requires CM intervention it's a Meta.SE-wide problem.